# javascript: prevent 2nd _blank window from opening in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, popup

I'm using a javascript to launch a "shadowbox" jquery lightbox window when a user logs in and hits submit on a html form.

firstly I want the jquery window to only launch on succesfull submit not on unsuccesful submit.
(i.e so if the users email and password is correct) - is there a way to do this?

The other problem im having is at the moment the jquery window pops up as expected but a 2nd target _blank window opens up at the same time because i am using `'this.target = 'formpopup';'`

i have tried to use `'e.preventDefault();'` to prevent the second window from opening and this does stop the 2 window from opening but it also stops the form from login the user in. is there anyway i can just prevent the 2nd window from opening at all in a new _blank window without removing the `'this.target = 'formpopup';'` as this is required for the jquery window to open up.

please can someone show me what to do, thank you.

HTML FORM:

```
  <form id="myform" form action="login.php" method="post" class="loginform">

Email
  <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="30" />

Password
<input type="password" name="password" maxlength="30" />

<input type="image" src="../PTB1/assets/img/icons/loginarrow1.png" name="submit" class="loginbutton" value="Login" />

            </form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform').submit(function() {
        Shadowbox.open({
        content:    '<iframe src="loginin.php" width="500" height="300" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden; border:none;"></iframe>',
        player:     "html",
        height:     300,
        width:      500
    });

        this.target = 'formpopup';
          e.preventDefault();





    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you need `this.target = 'formpopup';`? Also, Your `e.preventDefault()` line is causing an error, because there is no `e`. Check your error console.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `target="aNameOfTheWindow"` you will open the same window over and over.